# LAN with intermediate PC

Tags: networking, ethernet, ping

I have the following configuration:

**PC A** <---- ethernet ----> **PC B** <----- ethernet -----> **PC C**

The PC B has several ethernet ports. The IP address of each computer (all on the same subnet) is:
PC A: 192.168.3.5

PC B: 192.168.3.20

PC C: 192.168.3.30

I'm able to ping PC B from PC A (and conversely), I'm able to ping PC B from PC C (and conversely), but I'm not able to ping PC C from PC A. How should I configure the network interface on PC B to be able to send ping between PC A and C? (I'm on windows 7, but if you know how to do it on linux I'm interested too, the most important is which concept I'm missing to make it work)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing the concept of routing/switching as a normal OS isn't configured to forward traffic from one interface to the other. For Windows 7 you might be able to setup a static route using `route`. For Linux it might be enough to set `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to `1`, I'm not sure you would need `iptables`.

Comment: Nice question as you have thought to diagram things and give IP addresses. Basically the network setup you want is for PC B to act as a bridge which Seth has explained. Have you thought of connecting all of them instead to a $20 switch? No need to have B on all the time. If you want to monitor traffic, just buy a switch with port mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: bridging and routing.

If you want one subnet on both sides, the two interfaces must be joined to a *bridge* on the PC (essentially turning it into a switch/hub). On Windows you can do this by selecting both and selecting "Bridge interfaces"; on Linux, use `brctl`. This is the simplest option.

Routing, meanwhile, means you'd have *two* LANs (and different subnets) which can still communicate with each other; i.e. PC A (192.168.88.x) can reach PC C (192.168.99.x). For this you'll need to enable "IP forwarding" on the middle host (making it into a router), and adding routes for the opposite subnet on each end. This is a good option if you actually have two *networks* and want to keep them somewhat separate. (Enabling IPv4 routing on Windows can be a bit painful, unless you use "Internet Connection Sharing"...)